# MySql adding and dividing decimal columns

Tags: mysql

i think this one is simple but i cant find a good example.

What i have is three columns.  StartPrice EndPrice Dividens and results.  Each of these is a decimal(10,2) column in MySql.  What i'm looking for is (preferably) is an update statement that basically will do Dividens / (AddPrice + EndPrice)  and return the decimals.

Example:
Dividens (AddPrice + Endprice) = result
2.09 / (7.52 + 10.52) = .11
7.40 / (1.75 + 1.25) = 2.47

All columns are decimal(10,2)

I'm looking for basically

```
update tblmath  
set result = '<this is what i cant do>  
where result = null
```

Comment: You may want to include your actual table structure in here.

Comment: Are you looking to make an update that will return all new values that were set? Or was "update statement" supposed to be "select statement?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `tblmath` and you're trying to update a column called `result` to contain the result of the calculation, this should work for you:

```
update tblmath set result = Dividens / (AddPrice + Endprice) where result is null;
```

BTW: You misspelled "Dividends", but I preserved the misspelling in the SQL above.